# Preoder to BST construction

Tags: binary-search-tree, preorder

I am attempting to create a BST from an array of pre-order traversal. I wrote the following code, but can't figure out where am I making a mistake. The following code returns Nodes with values null. I am using the following approach:


10  8   4   5   14  12
I will partition it (after removing staring element):
8 4 5 and 14 12, (recursively).

```
public Node generateTree(int ar[], int low, int high) {
    if (ar.length == 0 || low > high)
        return null;

    if (low == high)
        return new Node(ar[low]);

    int partitionPoint  = findPartitionPoint(ar, low, high);

    Node root = new Node(ar[low]);

    if (partitionPoint != -1) {
        root.left = generateTree(ar, low + 1, partitionPoint);
        root.right = generateTree(ar, partitionPoint + 1, high);
    } else {
        root.left = generateTree(ar, low + 1, high);
    }
    return root;
}
private int findPartitionPoint(int ar[], int low, int high) {
    if (high >= ar.length)
        return -1;
    for (int x = low; x <= high; x++) {
        if (ar[x] > ar[low])
            return x-1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the culprit. The issue was with Traversal function which I wrote separately. The Node function here takes int value, however, in Traversal function, I was printing its String value (my Node class has both String and Integer as keys). Such a silly mistake!
The code appears correct.